# How can I stop aptana Outline view automatically collapsing?

Tags: aptana

I'm using aptana to work on a web document with a fair bit of javascript that's organised into functions. I want to be able to easily jump around the functions, so I selected aptana for the document explorer / outline view panel. It works fine, but when I'm typing the document it collapses all by itself, which drives me bananas.

How can I stop it doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Under the little arrow in the top right corner is an option to "Link with Editor". Turn this off and the Outline view should stay as you leave it rather than trying to match what you are doing in the editor.

Comment: Nope that doesn't do it. Tried with both the "Link with Editor" on and off. No joy.

Comment: You don't see any change in behavior when you toggle this option or you don't see the desired behavior?

Comment: Toggling the option makes no difference to the behaviour. When I type in the document pane, the tree in the Outline view collapses. I've tried updating aptana, and restarting it several times.

Comment: I don't know. I can tell you that toggling that option makes a noticeable difference in the Outline view's behavior in my installation (3.3.2.201302081546). Perhaps you have a conflicting plugin or are editing a different kind of file that confuses the program? I am testing on a mixed javascript/html/css/php file (.php).

Comment: The version I'm usign is 3.4.0.201304151603. I don't have any plugins installed. The file is javascript/html/css but not php.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing what Sarah suggested and I was unable to get the Outline View to NOT collapse when editing a .js file.

I looked through the documentation and tried different settings within the Outline tab without success. Expand All did expand all of the functions, objects, and variables, but when I edited one of the objects or functions, that one would then collapse in the Outline View. The problem is it would never expand itself even when I moved in to another section of the document.

I would think that after editing a section of the document, the Outline View should update to reflects the change without collapsing. If it does collapse, then it should expand once saved.

Comment: Thanks ryentzer, sounds similar to the behaviour I'm experiencing. My preference would be for it to stay expanded, but I can see why your suggestion would be a useful mode.

Answer (score 0):

It either collapses and expands by itself (link with editor is "on") or only collapses by itself when you change anything in the document (link with editor is "off"). I don't think this behaviour is what most of us, users, would expect. I hope they change it soon. It's one of the very flaws this otherwise great piece of software has.